# Index array of geopoints in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, geopoints, elasticsearch-mapping

Following is my (sample) Elastic search data which has a series of geo coordinates that I'm trying to index.

```
PUT geomap/_doc/1
{
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -10.8544921875,
          49.82380908513249
        ],
        [
          -10.8544921875,
          59.478568831926395
        ],
        [
          2.021484375,
          59.478568831926395
        ],
        [
          2.021484375,
          49.82380908513249
        ],
        [
          -10.8544921875,
          49.82380908513249
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

and this is the elasticsearch mapping I've created for it.

```
PUT geomap
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "geometry": {
        "properties": {
          "coordinates": { "type": "geo_point" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I tried to insert the data it did not work. I suspect it is due to the fact that I've got arrays of array coordinates. When I updated the sample dataset to single array of coordinates it worked (below).

```
PUT geomap/_doc/1
{
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        -10.8544921875,
        49.82380908513249
      ],
      [
        -10.8544921875,
        59.478568831926395
      ],
      [
        2.021484375,
        59.478568831926395
      ],
      [
        2.021484375,
        49.82380908513249
      ],
      [
        -10.8544921875,
        49.82380908513249
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I would be glad to know what mistake I've done in my mapping which doesn't let me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your doc is a polygon so you're gonna want to use [`geo_shape`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html) instead:

```
PUT geomap
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "geo_shape",
        "strategy": "recursive"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the "recursive" strategy too to [support more spatial queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#spatial-strategy) (at least in the newer ES releases).

```
PUT geomap/_doc/1
{
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -10.8544921875,
          49.82380908513249
        ],
        [
          -10.8544921875,
          59.478568831926395
        ],
        [
          2.021484375,
          59.478568831926395
        ],
        [
          2.021484375,
          49.82380908513249
        ],
        [
          -10.8544921875,
          49.82380908513249
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "type": "polygon"
  }
}
```

Notice how the coords array was wrapped in one more array to comply w/ the geojson standard and that the `type: polygon` attribute was added.